# Is there a way to provide someone a link to a specific query placed on this page?

Tags: links

I want to search for a doctor by her name through this public FORM.  Is there a way to link to the specific search results?

http://www.idfpr.com/LicenseLookUp/LicenseLookup.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

For example, let's select `Profession` as "DOCTOR-PHYSICIAN" and `Last Name` as "HAMILTON". Click `SEARCH` and on the resulting page, you'll see a link named `Printer Friendly View`. It has got the link to the search results, which is:

http://www.idfpr.com/LicenseLookUp/printthispage.asp?page=1&pro_cde=0036&lnme=hamilton&initial=&type=NAME&checkbox=on

Now you can easily find the direct link to the search results using the above line. Just change `printthispage.asp` with `results.asp`, and you're done:

http://www.idfpr.com/LicenseLookUp/results.asp?page=1&pro_cde=0036&lnme=hamilton&initial=&type=NAME&rowcount=15&checkbox=on